# exc_bad_access when calling dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks, dispatch-async

I have a ViewController that slides up. When you click "Save" it sends a request to the server. When the request is done, it dismisses the ViewController. I switched the NSURLConnection over to using async and blocks (https://github.com/rickerbh/NSURLConnection-Blocks). Dismissing the ViewController now throws "Thread 2: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS". I'm using ARC, if that matters.

```
- (IBAction) savePressed
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.com/items/create"]];

    //NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [NSURLConnection asyncRequest:request success:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response) {
        [self close];
    } failure:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [self close];
    }];
}

- (void) close
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here is the log

```
2012-10-24 10:32:43.780 Prayrbox[22268:1703] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1f21fd90: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   0x347dc927 WebThreadLock
2   0x36718615 <redacted>
3   0x366d0a85 <redacted>
4   0x3678d789 <redacted>
5   0x366c0637 <redacted>
6   0x366d50e7 <redacted>
7   0x368c1f11 <redacted>
8   0x366d4969 <redacted>
9   0x36744745 <redacted>
10  0x366907ad <redacted>
11  0x7ef71 -[ComposeViewController close]
12  0x7eec5 __36-[ComposeViewController savePressed]_block_invoke_0
13  0x82d8f __56+[NSURLConnection(Blocks) asyncRequest:success:failure:]_block_invoke_0
14  0x37e8811f <redacted>
15  0x37e96259 <redacted>
16  0x37e963b9 <redacted>
17  0x37b30a11 <redacted>
18  0x37b308a4 start_wqthread
[Switching to process 10755 thread 0x2a03]
[Switching to process 10755 thread 0x2a03]
[unknown](gdb)
```

I have spent 2 hours searching for help on this. If anyone knows what could help, please speak up! :)

Comment: Two questions for clarification: 1) Are you sure the completion handler is being called on the main thread? 2) NSURLConnection already has an asynchronous request method...have you tried using that? i.e. maybe it's a problem with the third party library you are using.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure. I'm pretty fresh to Objective C and don't know how to figure that out.
2) The category I'm using (see link in post) is wrapping a synchronous call in dispatch_async and provides blocks. If there is a better way to use blocks, I'd love to know.

Comment: For the first question, you can set a break point inside the completion handler and the stack trace that appears will tell you which thread it's being called on. NSURLConnection has a method + (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler that you should try out and see if you have the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first thought, I would agree with the above comment that you might be on the wrong thread when dismissing the view.

UI Stuff should be done on Main, so to enforce that, you can do:

```
-(void) close {
    if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(close)
                               withObject:nil
                           waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Rather than doing the performSelectorOnMainThread from your block, this will ensure that anytime it's called you'll be on main.

Comment: Yea, so, as I suggested, it sounds like the 3rd party library you are using is not actually dispatching the completion handler on the main thread. I don't know that dispatching a completion handler on the main thread is standard practice, but I always do. It shouldn't be the responsibility of the person using your framework to play with the threads.